# Is "What is bounty?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, articles

Jeff Atwood argues that "What is bounty?" is correct [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76474/minor-grammar-issue-what-is-bounty-link-missing-article/76487#76487), but is this really the case?

Comment: I would say _What is a bounty?_, in the same way I would say _What is a car?_; I don't find anything that reports the sentence _What is bounty_ is grammatically not correct.

Comment: Without a preceding article, such as in the title question, I would normally assume that "bounty" means "abundance."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's fine. What we're talking about is a noun spoken of as a representative of its class, not merely as an instance of it. Consider some parallels:

> What is art?
>
> What is beauty?
>
> What is language?

"What is bounty?" in that context is really a shortened way to say "What do we mean when we use the term 'bounty' on this site?" I, for one, have no objection to it at all.

Comment: Note: this only works for collective nouns; you couldn't say "*what is car?". I suspect the OP has a problem with the collective sense of bounty.

Comment: I have to disagree with this one. Sure, it's understood, but in formal (British) English it is *not* correct. `Bounty` is a countable - not a mass - noun (certainly not in this context), so an article (`a` would work) is definitely required here.

Comment: Art and beauty are abstract nouns.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine *in context*, i.e. when asked on this or any other site that uses a bounty system.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the title should be “What is *bounty*?”, or perhaps “What is ‘bounty’?”.  By comparison to “What is beauty?”, the question “What is bounty?” asks what the concept means rather than what the word means.

To illustrate, somewhat trivially:
Q: What is *happiness*?
A: *Happiness* is the state of <*insert favorite definition here*>.
Q: What is happiness?
A: Happiness is a warm puppy.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what other answerers have said, "what is a bounty" has a different meaning than you intend it to. Using that indefinite article implies that you're referring to a particular, though unidentified, bounty somewhere. If anything, "what are bounties" would be better.